# Stuck in an infinite for loop

Tags: java, android, google-maps, gps

My code is supposed to check whether a `LatLng` is within 3000 meters of the current `LatLng`. If it is, the program should put a marker on the map. But for some reason it gets stuck in an infinite `for` loop.

```
public void onStart() {
...
Log.d("how big is compareloc", "size "+compareLocations().size());// outputs : 4
            for(int mm=0;mm<compareLocations().size();mm++){
                HashMap<String, LatLng> test = compareLocations().get(mm);
                Log.d("LatLng positon", "marker pos "+test.get(TAG_LATLNG));
                    if(test.get(TAG_LATLNG)!=null){
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(test.get(TAG_LATLNG)).title("test"));
                    }
            }
...
}
```

This is my compareLocations() which compares my latlng with a list of latlngs:

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, LatLng>> compareLocations(){
        LatLng mLocation;
        gps = new GPSTracker(getActivity());
            if(gps.canGetLocation()) {
                double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                mLocation = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                Location mylocation = new Location("Test1");
                mylocation.setLatitude(mLocation.latitude);
                mylocation.setLongitude(mLocation.longitude);


                mdatabase.open();
        Cursor cCompare=mdatabase.getAllItems();
        for(int melon=0;melon<cCompare.getCount();melon++){
            HashMap<String, LatLng> points = new HashMap<String, LatLng>();
            double DBlat = mdatabase.getlat(melon);
            double DBlong = mdatabase.getlong(melon);
            LatLng myco = new LatLng(DBlat, DBlong);
            Location location = new Location("Test");
                location.setLatitude(myco.latitude);
                location.setLongitude(myco.longitude);
                if(mylocation.distanceTo(location)<=3000){
                    points.put(TAG_LATLNG, myco);
                    Log.d("Checking distance", "distance less than 300 meters");
                }else{
                Log.d("Checking distance", "distance is greater than 300 meters");
                }
                closelist.add(points);
            }
            mdatabase.close();
            } else {
                gps.showSettingsAlert();
            }
        return closelist;
    }
```

Comment: I would recommend picking a somewhat more readable style of code. While picking such is largely a matter of personal preference, I am having a very difficult time reading your code. Things such as putting spaces after semicolons that do not end lines and spaces before brackets that do/between brackets and other text on the same line would go a long way. This may also help with problems like how your `if(gps.canGetLocation())` appears to be missing a closing bracket, despite having an open one - I myself prefer the brackets-on-own-line style because it makes it easier to prevent such.

Comment: it does have a closing bracket, are u viewing this on a mobile? i fine my code is very readable. but i guess its personal preference. will double check.

Comment: I am reading this through the normal SO interface. I do not see a closing brace there, with the line `mdatabase.open();` being immediately followed by `Cursor cCompare=mdatabase.getAllItems();`. Additionally, I see lines like `}else{` that are somewhat more difficult to read than if you'd added spaces around the "else", and the `Log.d()` call within that else statement is not even indented. I'm not really sure why you appear to be very wary of using vertical space - I would recommend `else`s go at least on a line separate from the closing brace of the preceding `if` statement, myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each call to `compareLocations()` adds entries to some `closelist`. It keeps growing and growing and the `for` loop never terminates.

You probably want to

- call `compareLocations()` only once and cache the result
- build `closeList` from a fresh start on each call to `compareLocations()` instead of appending to some existing list

Comment: put my closeList array inside my compareLocations function. Thanks